# Focus en elemento hijo anidado

Tags: angular

Tengo un componente en cuyo interior tengo un input y un botón. Llamemos a este componente: hijo. Este último se utiliza varias veces dentro de un componente padre. Necesito que cuando hago click sobre un botón dentro del padre el focus se posiciones en un input de uno de los hijos específico.

Comment: Pon el código  así podremos ayudarte mejo

Comment: Coloca el codigo.